# Unusual sized freestanding bathtub drain flexhose

Tags: bathtub

I bought a freestanding tub online and it came with a 1 3/4 flexhose which doesn't fit my standard plumbing which is 1 1/2. Is there a way to make it fit? (It's made in China)

Comment: You say it "came with an 1 3/4" flex hose". Do you mean to say that this hose came pre-attached to the drain assembly? Can you not remove the entire drain assembly and replace it with a common drain fitting that accommodates your preferred drain tubing/connector sizes?

Comment: How about a picture? You can put a picture on **IMGUR** and post the link to it, we will insert it into your question.